# Jython - SyntaxError: mismatched input ',' expecting COLON

Tags: jython

I have this code that I wrote in python:

```
from Purchase import Transaction
from Purchase import MoneyStatement

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p= {Transaction('costco','me', 45, "AmEx"),Transaction('costco','me', 45, "AmEx")}
    ms= MoneyStatement('AmEx 10-19-2012', p)
    print(ms)
```

And it works in python, but when I try to run it in jython it gives me this error:

p= {Transaction('costco','me', 45, "AmEx"),Transaction('costco','me', 45, "AmEx")}

```
                               ^
```

SyntaxError: mismatched input ',' expecting COLON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in [Python 2.7 and 3](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features). It does not work in pre-2.7, which is what Jython (at least the current release, I vaguely recall 2.7 compatibility being worked on) supports. There is no set literal syntax in those versions. Use what you'd use on pre-2.7 CPython too: `set([item1, item2, ...])`

Comment: Hi, I just came across the same issue. Would you please be able to explain what do you refer to when you say "*it* does not work"? I'm not sure what's causing that error and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @EugeneS "It" is the set literal syntax `{x, y}` and the fix is to use the alternative spelling highlighted in the answer.